# Performance issues when hiding columns in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the `DataTable.column(index).visible(false)` method to hide columns in my application. However with a few hundred rows it takes almost 5 seconds hiding a couple of columns. Anyone know if it is possible to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try setting http://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth to false?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help and some other problems occurred. Good suggestion though!

Comment: Have a look here :-) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455296/datatables-dynamically-hide-show-column-too-slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455296/datatables-dynamically-hide-show-column-too-slow) I've tried to gather some useful hints. Maybe it'll help.