# datatables dynamically hide/show column too slow

Tags: jquery, datatables

My goal is to show/hide columns dynamically using datatables JQuery plugin. When I have around 500 rows it takes it forever to do it. I'm using new Datatables API 1.10.0.

```
$('#oats-detailed-view-button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                oatsTable.columns([6,7,8,9,10,11,12]).visible(true);
            });
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Did you checked this example :  [colVis](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columns.html) or [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/ryat69nc/)

Answer (score 1):

Having performance issues, I suggest in general about these steps:

1. remove unnecessary data
2. alter options of the service object
3. try using the service object in another way
4. Workaround and debugging the service object (if open source, i.e. inform the producer about findings)
5. agree with the producer to solve the problem, or use another service object

To 1: are you sure you have no unnecessary attributes, texts and events concerning your cells?

To 2: here is a hint of setting `autoWidth` to false, but it didn't help in the other thread. [Performance issues when hiding columns in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129953/performance-issues-when-hiding-columns-in-jquery-datatables)

In the options of DataTables API, there is one further possibility influencing performance: `deferRender`: http://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender -> are you sure your columns are only made visible? Maybe the browser has to create the HTML first, as it was not created while loading?

Further, in the DataTables manual/FAQ is an explanation of speeding up the table by altering the way it's built: http://datatables.net/faqs/index (scroll down to "DataTables is running slow").

To 3 and 4: I could think of having two html `div` containers seamlessly laying beside. `div` 1 contains columns 1 to 5, `div`2 contains columns 6 to 12. Then by switching `div` 2 on and off, all the columns would get visible/invisible at once. I could imagine that if you use only `visibiliy:hidden` and *not* `display:none`, the browser doesn't have to render new.